# Table: calculate the intermediate variable but not list them

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to list `{a,c}` but `c` is depend on `b`, suppose the dependence on `b` can not written as a simple function `c(b)`. **How can I create a list of `{a,c}` list without list out `b` in the intermediate.**

My workaround is this:

```
list = Table[{a, b = a^2, c = b^2}, {a, 0, 10, 1}];
listWanted = list[[All, {1, 3}]]
```

However suppose the intermediate variable is many, doing this is cumbersome, at least not neat. I just want to calculate these intermediate value but not list them.

Comment: Obviously it depends on what you're actually doing (this might be *too* minimal an example), but you can certainly do `list = Table[{a, (a^2)^2}, {a, 0, 10, 1}]`.

Comment: ...or, `Table[{a, b = a^2; c = b^2}, {a, 0, 10, 1}]`.

Comment: @J.M. This is just what I want, thanks!

Comment: @march I've said that `c` is can not be written as a simple function of `a`

Comment: Did you understand what I replaced? If so, please write an answer to your own question. :)

Comment: @J.M. I've done it.

Answer (score 2):

One can using the `;` operator to do the evaluation, but suppress the output. So the code can be the following as pointed out in the comment:

```
Table[{a, b = a^2; c = b^2}, {a, 0, 10, 1}]
```

Comment: Maybe you already know this, but chances are you don't: there is [more to ;](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18617/368) than one might expect!

Comment: @sebhofer thank foe the link, can you explain this code using the principal you linked?